# How to create String split extension with regex in Swift?

Tags: swift

I wrote extension that create `split` method:

```
extension String {
    func split(splitter: String) -> Array<String> {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByString(splitter)
    }
}
```

So in playground I can write:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

if str.split(",").count > 1{
    var out = str.split(",")[0]

    println("output: \(out)") // output: Hello
}
```

What do I need to make it work with regex like in Java:

```
str.split("[ ]+")
```

Because this way it doesn't work.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd start with this method here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7890148. Run that, break off the string until the start of the found range and keep doing it until it returns `NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, your split function has some redundancy. It is enough to return

```
return self.componentsSeparatedByString(splitter)
```

Second, to work with a regular expression you just have to create a `NSRegularExpression` and then perhaps replace all occurrences with your own "stop string" and finally separate using that. E.g.

```
extension String {
    func split(regex pattern: String) -> [String] {
        let template = "-|*~~*~~*|-" /// Any string that isn't contained in the original string (self).

        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let modifiedString = regex?.stringByReplacingMatches(
            in: self,
            range: NSRange(
                location: 0,
                length: count
            ),
            withTemplate: template /// Replace with the template/stop string.
        )
        
        /// Split by the replaced string.
        return modifiedString?.components(separatedBy: template) ?? []
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps better to put the Swift 5 version below or as a separate answer.